# Which non-Indoeuropean languages have noun-adjective agreement?

Tags: morphology, list-of-languages, nouns, adjectives, agreement

For example, agglutinative/fusional languages where case or possessive suffixes/endings must be attached both to a noun and all adjectives that modify it. Or any other kind of noun-adjective agreement.

Comment: I think in languages that have case, even outside Indo-European, it is more common than not that at least attributive adjectives agree with their head noun in case (and number). Possessive suffixes are a different matter; off the top of my head, I’m not aware of any languages that mark both nouns and adjectives modifying them for possessor.

Answer (score 18):

Egyptian and many of the older Semitic languages put a `/t/` on feminine nouns and any adjectives modifying them, and many also mark number (singular, dual, plural) on both. A few of these languages (e.g. Akkadian) also still have case systems, and adjectives must agree in case with the noun they modify.

Comment: Amazigh languages also use /t/ for marking the feminine and a masculine/feminine gender split is also attested in all branches

Comment: Modern Standard Arabic also has a case system, and adjectives agree with the noun they describe in case/number/gender

Comment: By "Egyptian", do you mean the Egyptian dialect of Arabic, or Coptic?

Comment: @T.E.D. Egyptian Arabic does not match that description.

Comment: @psmears - Its also not an "older Semitic language", I don't think, just a local flavor of modern Arabic. However, the sentence was phrased present-tense, and I thought Coptic was a "liturgical language" (no native speakers).

Comment: @T.E.D.: That's entirely right, though Coptic isn't an "older Semitic language" either :) (I guess that's why it's "Egyptian _and_ ... older Semitic languages). But yes, it doesn't have native speakers. (FWIW some people argue Modern Standard Arabic doesn't either...).

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm fairly sure that Draconis here means what linguists term “Middle Egyptian,” which is neither modern Egyptian Arabic nor Coptic (although Coptic is its descendant).

Answer (score 15):

In the Atlantic-Congo languages that have noun classes, and that is most of them, adjectives agree in the class with the noun they modify.

In the Bantu subfamily, the adjectives agrees by receiving the *class prefix* corresponding to the class of the noun, e. g. in Swahili:

> **m**tu **m**zuri — a nice person (Class 1)
> **wa**tu **wa**zuri — nice people (Class 2)

In Fula, a Senegambian language that has about [25 noun classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_language#Noun_classes), the adjective receives a *class suffix* and the *initial consonant mutation* into the [mutation degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_language#Consonant_mutation) corresponding to the class of the noun it modifies:

> loo*nde* **w**oɗee**re** — a red pot (Class NDE)
> loo*ɗe* **b**oɗee**je** — red pots (Class ƊE)

Answer (score 8):

In Finnish, adjectives agree with the nouns they modify in terms of case and number.

Answer (score 3):

In Burushaski, adjectives also agree in class/gender with the noun they modify.

Answer (score 2):

There is a noun-adjective agreement in Georgian (for consonnant endings), in Chechen (class agreement), in Finnish, in Estonian, in Arabic, in Hebrew...